# Debug only constructors, not compiled in Release Mode

Tags: c#, debugging

Is there any way to create a "Debug Only" contructor which is not compiled in release mode?

The two solutions I've found so far are :

- surrounds the constructor with an #if DEBUG.  But it can be quite cumbersome if you have many methods/constructors
- Use the **ConditionalAttribute** but it does not apply to constructors, nor to methods returning anything but void

Ideally, an attribute identical to Conditional but with an extended scope would be awesome.

Thanks for your help.

```
public class Foo
{

/// <summary>
/// Main constructor
/// </summary>
public Foo(){}

/// <summary>
/// Debug only constructor
/// </summary>
[Conditional("DEBUG")] //does not compile, wished behavior
internal Foo(bool dummy){}
}
```

**EDIT**

As it had been pointed by Cheng Chen & Erik Philips below, this question was an XY problem. 
The broader picture was : my main constructor loads heavy ressources from the Internet. But I wanted to debug with a fast loading constructor loading dummy values, testing only specific functions. I solved it by creating a dummy class instead of a dummy constructor of a working class. There may be better solutions to this problem.

So, bottom line is :

- There is no attribute working on constructors similar to **ConditionalAttribute**
- You can surround with a compiler directive #if DEBUG to prevent compilation of a specific constructor/method in Release Mode. You can as well group them into a partial class for better readability.
- But, if you need such a constructor, think twice if there are no other options.

Comment: **Why** do you need this?  [This is an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858), that is you *Think* doing this will solve some other problem and instead of asking how to solve that problem, you want us to solve the problem with your attempted solution.

Comment: Alright, point taken. Bottom line : I need a fast loading constructor for debugging, whereas my regular constructor takes a lot of ressources. But I don't want this constructor to be available anywhere else. Internal maybe sufficient

Comment: Well why do you need a fast loading constructor (you're still telling us about your attempted solution, than the actual problem).  What are you doing that is requiring a different constructor during debugging?

Comment: Loading a dataset with default values instead of their actual values (collected from the places all over the Internet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement looks strange to me. I think you will get better answers if you explain from the very beginning, the current question is much more like an attempted solution to your original requirement.

To answer your question directly, we can use a factory here.

```
public class Foo
{
    private Foo(){}
    private Foo(bool dummy){}

    public static Foo FromNormal() { }

#if DEBUG
    public static Foo FromDummy(bool dummy) { }
#endif
}
```

Comment: You're right, done in an Edit. Btw, I think you are missing the return type for the Factory constructors:  public static Foo FromNormal() { } and public static Foo FromDummy(bool dummy) { }. Is it a typo?

Comment: @XavierAM Thanks, I typed the code directly in browser, made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have more problems then the `Conditional` *Attribute*.

You can't have two *Constructors* with the same signature. Anyway, that aside (as I am sure it's only a typo), let's look at the documentation:

[Compiler Error CS0592](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0592)

> Attribute 'attribute' is not valid on this declaration type. It is
> valid on 'type' declarations only.
>
> When you define an attribute, you define what constructs it can be
> applied to by specifying an AttributeTargets value. In the following
> example, the MyAttribute attribute can be applied to interfaces only,
> because the AttributeUsage attribute specifies
> AttributeTargets.Interface. The error is generated because the
> attribute is applied to a class (class A).

It just so happens the `ConditionalAttribute` is defined as follows:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
```

[AttributeUsage (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/attributeusage)

> Determines how a custom attribute class can be used.
> AttributeUsageAttribute is an attribute you apply to custom attribute
> definitions. The AttributeUsage attribute enables you to control:

- Which program elements attribute may be applied to. Unless you restrict its usage, an attribute may be applied to any of the following program elements: assembly, module, field, event, method, param, property, return, type
- Whether an attribute can be applied to a single program element multiple times.
- Whether attributes are inherited by derived classes.

So looking at the documentation, you just can't use this *Attribute* on a *Constructor*.

However, what you can do is use a *Compiler Directive*:

[#if (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

> When the C# compiler encounters an `#if` directive, followed eventually
> by an `#endif` directive, it compiles the code between the directives
> only if the specified symbol is defined.

```
public class Foo
{    
   public Foo() { }
   
#if DEBUG
   internal Foo2(Something something) { }
#endif
}
```

Or

```
public class Foo
{
#if DEBUG
   public Foo() { }
#else
   public Foo() { }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo, I corrected the signature of the constructor.

Comment: Your answer actually explains well why it is not working but my question was : is there any workaround to get a "ConditionalAttribute like" behavior on constructors.

Comment: @XavierAM yes use a compiler directive, you cant change the attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [partial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) classes.

Basically you split the class into two files. One for normal implementation and the other for the *Debug Only* implementation, which is wrapped in the `#if DEBUG` compiler directive.

```
// Foo.cs
public partial class Foo
{

   /// <summary>
   /// Main constructor
   /// </summary>
   public Foo(){}
}

// Foo.Debug.cs
public partial class Foo
{
  #if DEBUG

  /// <summary>
  /// Debug only constructor
  /// </summary>
  internal Foo(bool dummy){}

  #endif
}
```

This way you can organize all methods, members, etc which will not be compiled in release mode in the same file.